# Label isn't being displayed in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My app's theme is this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

Means no action bar. But I want an activity to have an action bar only but no status bar, so I created a style for that activity:

```
<style name="chapter_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

And the manifest file:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ChapterOne"
        android:theme="@style/chapter_theme"
        android:label="Chapter One">

    </activity>
```

To get rid of the status bar, I added the following code in the java file of that activity:

```
 // To remove status bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter_one);
```

Can't figure out what's wrong

EDIT: I got it what was wrong. The action bar's and its title's color was white, so no one could see the title written there. I changed the background color of the action bar.

Now I wanna know how to change the title's color?

Comment: you want to show label on Toolbar

Comment: Yeah on the toolbar

Comment: no i didn't and why should i

Comment: do you used custom toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to add label

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
     if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setTitle("put your label here");

    }
```

Comment: No it's not working, I have no idea what the fruit is going on.

Comment: It was my bad, title's color and toolbar's color was same.

Comment: So you can change color of toolbar dear any problem in that

Comment: Nope! @Nikhil Sharma